# Beginning of Renders are Choppy | Cycles Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation

When I render an animation, the first several frames are choppy and not smooth. This has been happening for a while and I'm not sure why it occurs -- it's only within the first 24 frames. This has occurred with both 2D and 3D animations.

I tried changing my fps and extending keyframe durations (both for 2D and 3D projects), yet the results remain the same.

The included .gif is a converted .avi rendered at 60 frames per second over 250 frames. It looks like the gif completely skipped over the choppy frames -- you'll notice it jumps.

Res: 1920 x 1920 | File Format: H.264 | Format: AVI | Codec: H.264

**EDIT:** I have tried reducing frame rate in addition to extending frames; I've also tried adding motion blur.

PROJECT FILE: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9m9vbrOjVXBTXpzdlVTM2IwZ3c

[image: example]

Comment: It would help a lot if you add a detailed description of the scene and the settings you are using. Are those cubes traveling on a curve using the follow path constraint? Try increasing the curve resolution https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VOuh.png

Comment: @cegaton if OP has the same problem as me it's irrelevant to the scene. As  for settings it's always present with H.264 encoding. It's gone after rendering animation to images.

Comment: @LukeD I can't presume anything... there is not enough information on the question for an answer... but it could very well be just unrealistic expectations to play 60fps at a data rate that the computer cannot sustain... How would we know...? This is the guess-stack-exchange...

Comment: @cegaton I'll provide later on .blend file and rendered animation file to inspect. And it's doesn't matter how much FPS you are rendering.

Comment: @cegaton I'm not using a curve, I set manual keyframes every 5 frames or so. The beginning of all renders are choppy. In my experience it's irrelevant to how the scene is set up, I experience the same issue.

I have two PCs, one at work and one at home. The one at home is optimized for animation, yet this still occurs.

Comment: @lukjach98 We need a .Blend file to troubleshoot. There can be several things wrong. It could be your render settings, your animation settings, your sequence settings, etc. etc.

Comment: @Einar I've uploaded the project file. Sorry about that. To be clear, I've changed the frame rate several times and it had no effect. I've just added motion blur and it looks slightly better.